# What is the grammatical structure of: 我把你们带到茶馆来。

Tags: translation, grammar

I was reading New Practical Chinese Reader Chpater 27 and stumbled upon the following sentence: 我把你们带到茶馆来。  While the meaning of the sentence is pretty clear, I have trouble understanding its underlying structure and hope someone can help me.

Thus far I figured out: You use 把 together with 带到 that something has been moved from one to place to another. In this case: The place of 你们 to 茶馆。

However, what is the idea behind 来 ？

Google translate provides the following translation for the two sentences:

我把你们带到茶馆来。I will bring you to the tea house.

我把你们带到茶馆。I will take you to the tea house.

Considering the context of these sentences however: The action all took place in the past. That's why I am a bit wary about Google Translate suggestion.

Can someone explain what the underlying structure of the sentence is - what can be deduced / what cannot be deduced?

Answer (score 5):

Here unfortunately, 来 doesn't indicate completion. Instead, it indicates direction of an action.
我把你们带到茶馆来=我把你们带来茶馆（indicating that the speaker's location is (or was, depending on context) 茶馆）
Comparison:
我把你们带到茶馆去=我把你们带去茶馆（indicating that the speaker is not at 茶馆）

Comment: Judging by the sentence alone, your post makes the most sense. Nonetheless, this grammatical structure makes me uncomfortable - the "来" feels redundant or at the least out of place..

Comment: I have however found another possibilty here: https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Using_%22lai%22_to_connect_two_verb_phrases

If above sentence would continue with another phrase, would 来 then be transalted with "so that" or "in order to"? Would the 来 then be necessary for the construction to work?

Comment: of course this seems to be the 1st most obvious choice coming to most people's mind agreeing with 1st entry in standard dictionaries:＂现代汉语词典＂（１）用在动词后，表示动作朝着说话人所在的地方：把锄头拿～｜各条站线传～了振奋人心的消息. Since it was not made clear that speaker was at 茶馆 some users offered the less obvious, less frequent alternative.

Answer (score 1):

bkrs: (Ru) after VP 4) -lai, lái indicates completion (result) of action by main verb 
信笔写来,一觉醒来,这人看来年纪不小, 你且听我道来,  屈指算来, 已经十五年了,说来话长

＂现代汉语词典＂（１９８３年 北京）来（２）用在动词后，表示动作的结果：examples 1-3 as above|看来今年超产没有问题｜想来你是早有准备的

Answer (score 1):

If you are following NPCR, I suggest you take a look at lesson 16 on book 2. You should first understand 我把照片带来了.

带 (carry) + 来 ("here") = 带来 (bring)

我把照片带来了。I brought the photo.

Compare:

我把照片带去了。I took the photo there.

带 (carry) + 去 ("there") = 带去 (take "there")

The translations "take/bring" to the word 带 don't quite express its real meaning. It doesn't show if you are taking something "here" or "there". These meanings are showed by the directional complements 来 and 去. Take a look at lesson 16's grammar.

The same thing is happening on 我把你们带到茶馆来, that is "carry here" (brought) to the tea house.

Cheers

Answer (score -4):

汉语博大精深。"来"表示意愿和热情。。。。。。。。。。。。。。。。。。。。。。。。。。。。